# How can I map over these 2 json responses and create a struct containing mapped items

Tags: json, swift, codable

I have 2 `JSON` objects I am working with.

The first `JSON` object represents an array of content articles.

```
[
   {
      "score":0.0,
      "id":"508b860c-0134-47ef-81ea-6337f6be7845",
      "fields":{
         "summary":{
            "id":"2c20b530-81e9-48ab-8507-b0388289e156",
            "fieldType":"ENTRY"
         },
         "mainImage":{
            "id":"acf96f3c-5824-4f9a-a1ed-b6a994bc25a4",
            "fieldType":"ASSET"
         }
      },
      "status":"PUBLISHED"
   },
   {
      "score":0.0,
      "id":"05fcd9cb-c055-4728-a244-ec91d1145200",
      "fields":{
         "summary":{
            "id":"b1912a52-0a1c-42df-9eac-15a586feae8b",
            "fieldType":"ENTRY"
         },
         "mainImage":{
            "id":"129a4792-b0e4-46e3-ab6c-3801d292c378",
            "fieldType":"ASSET"
         }
      },
      "status":"PUBLISHED"
   },
   {
      "score":0.0,
      "id":"8e8f4731-a8dc-4936-bea5-e33c8e63256a",
      "fields":{
         "summary":{
            "id":"886ea061-79fb-4364-b147-7f1f542a672d",
            "fieldType":"ENTRY"
         },
         "mainImage":{
            "id":"81bc9e4f-12c1-4ee1-bb11-a5dce883b23f",
            "fieldType":"ASSET"
         }
      },
      "status":"PUBLISHED"
   }
]
```

Each item in the array contains an `id` property that represents the content article. Each article object then has a sub object that lists the assets for that article, with a unique `id` for each asset.

I must loop over each article and extract the the assets with a `fieldType` of `ASSET`.

I then make a network request to a different endpoint for that asset body.

Each of those requests returns a response that looks like -

*note these are three requests using the `id` prop, not an array from a single request.*

```
{ 
   "id":"acf96f3c-5824-4f9a-a1ed-b6a994bc25a4",
   "createdAt":"2019-11-06T17:21:40Z",
   "space":"main",
   "contentType":"image/png",
   "fileName":"cf43c65d-1a37-48ff-a0db-47e84be3a554.png",
   "storageUri":"http://first-article-asset-id"
}

{ 
   "id":"129a4792-b0e4-46e3-ab6c-3801d292c378",
   "createdAt":"2019-11-06T17:21:40Z",
   "space":"main",
   "contentType":"image/png",
   "fileName":"cf43c65d-1a37-48ff-a0db-47e84be3a554.png",
   "storageUri":"http://second-article-asset-id"
}

{ 
   "id":"81bc9e4f-12c1-4ee1-bb11-a5dce883b23f",
   "createdAt":"2019-11-06T17:21:40Z",
   "space":"main",
   "contentType":"image/png",
   "fileName":"cf43c65d-1a37-48ff-a0db-47e84be3a554.png",
   "storageUri":"http://third-article-asset-id"
}
```

I need to then match up this response with the article Id of the first response by matching the id property on the `fields` sub object with the id property of the responses above.

I would like to end up with an array of something like -

```swift
struct MatchedAsset {
   let articleId: String // eg: this would be 508b860c-0134-47ef-81ea-6337f6be7845"
   let asset: ArticleAsset // eg: this would be the result of fetching acf96f3c-5824-4f9a-a1ed-b6a994bc25a4
}
```

I have modelled the responses here -

```swift
struct Article: Codable {
    let id: String
    let score: Int
    let status: String
    let fields: [String: ArticleAsset]
}

enum FieldType: String, Codable {
    case asset = "ASSET"
    case entry = "ENTRY"
}

struct ArticleAsset: Codable {
    let fieldType: FieldType
    let id: String
}

struct AssetContent: Codable {
    let contentType: String
    let createdAt: String
    let fileName: String
    let id: String
    let space: String
    let storageUri: String
}
```

I am able to get up to the point I have both the articles and asset request responses in 2 arrays of `[Article]` and `[AssetContent]` but am at a complete loss how to work with these collections.

Any attempts so far have been incredibly loopy with lots of nested `map`,`filter` and `forEach` loops and did not seem to work.

Comment: you can create new property in Article for example: `assetContent` and afer downloading AssetContent set this property with this value. It creates one object, easy to work with. Another solution can be a protocol, which can be implemented in both structs.

Comment: Maybe I haven't been clear, by the time I have both data, I have 2 arrays. How can I map over these and be sure I am setting the correct props on the correct article

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution to merge the two arrays,

```
var articles = [Article]() 
var assets = [AssetContent]()

var merged = [Article]()
articles.forEach { article in
    if let asset = article.fields.values.first(where: { $0.fieldType == .asset }) { 
        var updated = article
        updated.asset = assets.first(where: {$0.id == asset.id})
        merged.append(updated)
    } else {
        merged.append(article)
    }
}
```

This solution adds the AssetContent to the Article so you need a new property in Article

```
struct Article: Codable {
    let id: String
    let score: Int
    let status: String
    var asset: AssetContent?
    let fields: [String: ArticleAsset]
}
```

Of course you could have any struct as output of the merge, like a completely new one but here I tried to keep it as simple as possible